# MySQL Error Code: 1060

Tags: mysql, duplicates, syntax-error, alter-table

so for this, the goal is to add a column to a table called ENROLLMENT called FullFeePaid and to populate the column (assuming its null) but the only two possible answers can be Yes or No comparing data from another table called Course.

So I type the following command using alter however I keep getting a message where there's a duplicate, even i've never made a column called FullFeePaid.

But before that I kept getting an error saying there's a syntax error where it says

```
"set e.FullPaid = if(c.fee - e.amount <= 0 'yes', 'no')". 


SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
ALTER TABLE enrollment
    add fullfeepaid varchar(45) NULL;

UPDATE ENROLLMENT as e
    JOIN COURSE as c on e.CourseNumber = c.CourseNumber
set e.FullFeePaid = if(c.fee - e.amountpaid <= 0 'yes', 'no')
where e.CourseNumber = c.CourseNumber;

select * 
from enrollment;
```

Comment: Why would you duplicate your data in the first place? 0,1 in one table or yes, no in another table... what's the point of this?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma between the condition and the result your want to return if it evaluates as `true`:

```
UPDATE ENROLLMENT as e
    JOIN COURSE as c on e.CourseNumber = c.CourseNumber
SET e.FullFeePaid = if(c.fee - e.amountpaid <= 0, 'yes', 'no')
-- Missing comma in the OP ---------------------^
WHERE e.CourseNumber = c.CourseNumber;
```